# Submission of dynamically generated input fields

Tags: 8, javascript, webforms

I have created data entry form using Drupal 8 Webform (Yaml forms),
Part of the form is table field which hosts dynamically generted textfields using jquery shown below:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var input="";
    var column="";
    $(".add-row").click(function(){
    var new_row =jQuery('<tr>');
    input= jQuery('<input>').attr({type: 'text',name:'names[]'});
    column=jQuery('<td>').append(input);
    input= jQuery('<input>').attr({type: 'text',email:'emails[]'});
    column=jQuery('<td>').append(input);
    new_row.append(column);
        $("table tbody").append(new_row);
    });
});
```

However, to my surprise when I hit submit button of the form all other fields are submitted except the fields
which have been generated dynamically on the table field.It seems Drupal 8 can not recognize the dynamically generated input 
fields

So my question how can I make Drupal 8 recognize my dynamically generated input fields. I want to see the data in these fields in
the database. Please help. Your assistance will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The [WebformSubmissionStorage](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/src/WebformSubmissionStorage.php#n932) service uses the list of elements associated with the webform to properly store the data.  You are going to have to create an Element and WebformElement plugin definition that defines the element type (ie multiple, composite, etc...) and then attach your JS as a library.

Comment: Any sample code @jrockowitx - i can not figure out. Otherwise i was thinking of creating a hidden field which will capture the table data (in json format) using jquery during submission